# Add syntax-highlighting for KML

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

[xml](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml) tag has `lang-xml` syntax highlighting (you can see it in at the bottom of [XML tag info](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/xml/info)). But tag [kml](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kml) doesn't, although it's XML based language.

So when question have [xml](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml) tag everythink works OK (e.g. [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/213300/106798)). But when it has [kml](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kml) syntax highlighting is not working properly (e.g. [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3020/106798)). Sometimes XML syntax highlighting is added explicitly via HTML comment `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` like [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33102/106798) but this can be achieved automatically for every KML question if this suggestion would be implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [kml](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kml) tag now has XML syntax highlighting applied:

[image]